# Using Facebook's invariant vs if throw

Tags: javascript, error-handling, invariants

I've been looking at various Node.js projects' source, and I've noticed that some people use [invariant](https://github.com/zertosh/invariant). From what I understood, `invariant` is a tool that lets you put assertions in your code, and raise errors as needed.

## Question:

When would you favor using `invariant` vs throwing errors the traditional way?

```
// Using invariant
function doSomething(a, b) {
   invariant(a > b, 'A should be greater than B');
}

// If throw
function doSomething(a, b) {
   if(a <= b) {
      throw new Error('A should be greater than B');
   }
}
```

Comment: Probably just because it's one line instead of multiple lines. Same kind of pattern as `Preconditions` in Google guava (Java)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are a few reasons:

- It's easier to read when you want to stack them. If you have, say, 3 preconditions to validate, you always see `invariant(x ...`, and it's easy to see what's being checked:

---

```
function f(xs, x) {
    // all the invariants are lined up, one after another
    invariant(xs.type == x.type, "adding an element with the same type");
    invariant(xs.length != LIST_MAX_SIZE, "the list isn't full");
    invariant(fitting(x), "x is fitting right in the list");
}
```

Compare with the usual throw approach:

```
function f(xs, x) {
    if (xs.type != x.type)
       throw new Error("adding an element with the same type");
    if (xs.length == LIST_MAX_SIZE)
       throw new Error("the list isn't full");
    if (!fitting(x))
       throw new Error("x is fitting right in the list");
}
```

---

- It makes it easy to eliminate it in release build.

  It's often that you want preconditions checked in dev/test, but don't want them in release because of how slow they'd be.
  If you have such an `invariant` function, you can use a tool like babel (or some other) to remove these calls from production builds
  (this is somewhat like how D does it).

Comment: Ah, disabling the assertions in prod builds sounds like a great idea. Kind of hard to do that using the `if throw` approach.

Answer (score 5):

`zertosh/invariant` allows to add [code guards](https://www.jondjones.com/frontend/javascript/npm-packages-for-javascript-developers/guards-in-javascript-using-invariant/)

As said in the readme it is **A way to provide descriptive errors in development but generic errors in production**.

however it is a replication of some internal facebook's systems and imo is pretty bad documented and not maintained. Scary thing is the 4.4M uses :thinking:

- nothing will be striped out of the box
- if you don't have a build tool that somehow remove your message in production you will still have the original error
- the usage in node is for ssr/react native, or useless outside of the "we have less lines" thing
- it uses `error.framesToPop` which also is a facebook thing

see: https://github.com/zertosh/invariant/issues?q=is%3Aissue

Note:
A better aproach will be to wait for the es proposal `throw inline` and actually do

```js
cond || throw x
cond ?? throw x
```

that way the error will not be evaluated anyway and stripped if cond includes a falsy var env in the browser

Answer (score 0):

### Usefulness in TypeScript projects

...Adding on to previous answers of making it easier to read, less lines of code, stripping from dev builds:

If you're using typescript, you can use it help narrow down types + get dev time feedback.

Imagine the scenario below:
We're reading from our filesystem in node/js, the type system has no idea what's in there, so we need a runtime check, for that we'll want an invariant method to make runtime checks like this easy.

Note:

- there is a modern & popular version Facebook's `invariant` package called `tiny-invariant` which I recommend called `tiny-variant`: https://github.com/alexreardon/tiny-invariant

[image]